# simple calculator that shows the different between 2 numbers in C#

Tags: c#, calculator, calc

first of all sorry for my broken language. i would like to create a calculator that shows the different between 2 numbers in C#
i tried to make it but i always end up with adding the textbox 1 to the textbox 2 and displaying the total in text box 3, which i don't want to do
please see the GUI , it's simple
i also would like to make the number in green color if the different is positive and red if the different is negative. see the picture 
thanks!
[simple gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ziw26.png)

Comment: what code have you written to try to solve it?

Comment: *"but i always end up with adding the textbox 1 to the textbox 2"* - From the description it sounds like you want to *subtract* instead of *add*.  Perhaps the problem is a misunderstanding of basic arithmetic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Write this code in the click event of calculate button**

```
    private void Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            int diff = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
            textBox3.Text = diff.ToString();
            if (diff >= 0)
            {
                textBox3.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
                textBox3.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("PLZ Enter the balances");
        }
    }
```

[image: Result]

Comment: AWESOME JOB !!!!!!!
but the only problem is that if one of the textboxes is blank , and you click button1 the program will crash, is there anyway to handle this ?

Comment: look back to my edit